# Can't change login shell

Tags: command-line, bash

I try to change my default shell to my own shell `opsh` (The Open Shell) but it doesn't work:

```
$ echo $0
bash
developer@1604:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/opsh
developer@1604:~$ chsh -s /bin/opsh 
Password: 
chsh: /bin/opsh is an invalid shell
developer@1604:~$ more /etc/shells 
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/usr/bin/fish
/bin/ksh93
/bin/rksh93
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
/bin/mksh
/bin/mksh-static
/bin/opsh
/usr/bin/opsh
```

I can actually execute my shell as /bin/opsh

```
$ /bin/opsh 
$ echo $0
/bin/opsh
$ uname -a|grep Linux
Linux 1604 4.4.0-77-generic #98-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 26 08:34:02 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual path to your shell binary is obviously

```
/bin/opsh
```

but you added it in `/etc/shells` as

```
/usr/bin/opsh
```

(You may as well change the name to `oopsh`... ;-))

Comment: :confused: I see both `/bin/opsh` and `/usr/bin/opsh` in the OP's `more /etc/shells` output. Does `/etc/shells` ignore the first one?

Comment: @steeldriver , OP any problem with execution of /usr/bin/opsh